# Does a USB-C male to Micro-B female cable/adapter exist?

Tags: usb, cable, usb-3, adapter

I'm looking for a USB-C male (3.1) to Micro-B (3) female cable or adapter. The use case would be to allow last-option charging of a USB-C laptop (e.g. Pixel 2) from a standard phone/tablet charger (Micro-B).

Comment: http://www.cablestogo.com/product/28869/usb-2.0-usb-c-to-usb-micro-b-adapter-m-f-black

Comment: According to the [Help Center](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), this question is off-topic.

Comment: Thanks @Jamal. I did some research before posting and found this to be the best StackExchange site to post this on. So I posted it here. I did read the linked page and still feel this is okay to ask.

Comment: Then we'll see whether or not the community decides to close this.

Comment: Josh is asking if one exists, not where to buy one, its a legit question imho. One way to prove one exists is to link to one for sale as I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a cable on the site below,  I found it by googling "USB-C male to Micro-B female adapter"

you might also look at the monoprice.com site

http://www.cablestogo.com/product/28869/usb-2.0-usb-c-to-usb-micro-b-adapter-m-f-black.

[image]

Comment: How exactly would you provide an answer to this question? I do not believe anything needs to be changed in this answer, because he gave a description of what he searched for to find the product. This isn't like a software/hardware troubleshooting question where an answer needs to be long and specific.

Comment: @Ulincsys:  The problem with any answer where the information is contained in a link is that if the link breaks, the answer isn't useful.  What Moab did with the edit solves that problem.  To answer your question, this is how you would do it.  If you only looked at the post-edit version, you correctly recognized a good answer, so congrats.

Comment: @fixer1234 I had not realized that the question was edited until you pointed it out, thank you.

Comment: Close, but it's not USB 3. :) This question's about to get deleted anyway!

Comment: I accepted it anyway for now, I don't see any alternative with a USB-3 Micro-B female connector, but this one is close enough (for me).

Comment: " I don't see any alternative with a USB-3 Micro-B female connector "  It's not likely you will, such an adapter violates the USB spec.  If you do find one then stay away from it, it will not pass USB testing by nature of the connector so there's no knowing where else they broke something.  I know this is old but it is popping up as related on more recent Q&As, people are still finding this in their searches.

Answer (score 0):

Male USB 3.1 C to male USB 3 micro-B seem easy enough to find but ones that have female USB 3 micro-B connectors, not so much. Perhaps a gender adapter.

[USB 3.0 Type Micro B Gender Changer, Female to Female](http://www.networktechinc.com/cgi-bin/keemux/usb3-mbfmbf.html)

[image: USB 3.0 Type Micro B Gender Changer, Female to Female]

[Belkin 3.1 USB-C to Micro-B Cable](http://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F2CU031/)

[image: Belkin 3.1 USB-C to Micro-B Cable]

Comment: USB gender changing adapters break the spec and so are not likely to achieve the desired result.  The USB-C port on the cable will be wired to indicate a male connector on the opposite end so putting a gender changer on the other end is lying to the connected device.  This is very bad because by telling the USB-C end that there is a male B connector on the opposite end it will *supply* power, not sink power.  The attached power supply will also supply power.  This will likely result in damaged hardware.  DO NOT DO THIS!

Comment: @MacGuffin There are generally two parts to any spec: The spec, and reality. So. How does this work, really? Also, this was 6 years ago.

Comment: In reality if the USB-C to micro-B cable works correctly on a device, like a hard drive, then it is supplying power.  If it is not supplying power then the drive will not light up.  Putting a gender changer on the cable cannot tell the USB-C laptop that it is supposed to take power in from a power supply, there's no wires or other means to communicate that.  The power brick with the micro-B connector is quite likely a "dumb" 5 volt power supply with no logic to check for power on the port.  In reality this will not charge the laptop.